# How to integrate $1/(x^3 + 8)$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need some suggestions to solve this integral:

$$\int_{1}^{3} \frac{1}{x^3 + 8} dx$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Hint:** Use partial fractions: $x^3+8=(x+2)(x^2-2x+4)$.

Answer (score 5):

1) split $\dfrac{1}{x^3 +8}$ in a sum of $\dfrac{\alpha}{x - \beta}$ or $\dfrac{\alpha x + \beta}{x^2 + \gamma x + \delta}$ ;

2) then you should be able to calculate those classical integrals.